# Custom Theme Module Can Not Be Resolved

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am tempting to get started on creating a custom theme app for my Angular 5 app that uses Angular Material 2. Following the directions, I added my `src/diabetes-chart-theme.scss` to the .angular-cli.json in the `styles` key. But when I compile, I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css' in '/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src'`.

I am guessing the scss is not compiling successfully so the compiled css file is not there.

Any ideas? The error output is pretty noisy as it is complaining about missing node_modules(no issues if I do not use a custom theme).

.angular-cli.json

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "diabetes-chart-theme.scss"
  ],
```

---

src/diabetes-chart-theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// **Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!**
@include mat-core();

// Define the default theme (same as the example above).
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-theme:   mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent);

// Include the default theme styles.
@include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);


// Define an alternate dark theme.
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);
$dark-theme:   mat-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);
```

---

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css' in '/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src'
resolve '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css' in '/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
    resolve as module
      /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/one/github/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules
        using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/package.json (relative path: ./prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /home/one/node_modules
        using description file: /home/one/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/one/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /home/one/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules
        using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/package.json (relative path: ./prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src
        using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src
        using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src)
          using description file: /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/package.json (relative path: ./src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css doesn't exist
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/node_modules]
[/home/one/github/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts]
[/home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts]
[/home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js]
[/home/one/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.ts]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css.js]
[/home/one/github/diabetes-charts/src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css]
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/styles.css 3:10-212
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./src/styles.css ./src/diabetes-chart-theme.scss

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: How on earth did that happen? What does your `styles.css` look like? How come it became this? `@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.css`

Answer (score 1):

Change your angular-cli.json to :

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/diabetes-chart-theme.scss"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference to `diabetes-chart-theme.scss` in `.angular-cli.json`. Rename `styles.css` to `styles.scss` and update `.angular-cli.json`. Now, import your `diabetes-chart-theme.scss` from your `styles.scss`. This assumes that both files are under `src` and your `.angular-cli.json` file has `"root": "src"` for the app.